# need help in database designing for leave application module php

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have an database for employee management system containing `user_table`

> (id, email, name, pass, emp_type)

next on is for `leave_application_table`

> (id,email,sdate,edate,manager,reason,status,remark)
>
> emp_type=(director/Manger/executive)

and all three group have different number of leaves in their account like

`director`

> (Sick_Leave=10,Casual_L=6)

`Manager`

> (S_L=8,C_L=5)etc.

how to save these data in database table need some ideas that doesn't slow up the database.
Thank you in adavance

Comment: This sounds like a very useful module, so good luck with it. Unfortunately, this question is too broad to be answerable at present.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create an employees table:

id, employee_type_id, email, name, pass, sdate, edate

---

An employee_types table (three records in it, one for direct / manager / exect:

id, employee_id, max_sick_leaves, max_casual_days

---

An employee_days_off table

id, employee_id, day_off(DATE), type, reason, status, remark

---

type in the employee_days_off table would correspond with the max_sick_leaves, etc... in the employee_types table.

So if the same employee took two days off, one casual and one sick day, the records in the days off table would look like...

1, 22, 2016-04-22, "sick_day", "some reason", "some status", "some remark"
2, 22, 2016-04-23, "casual_day", "some reason", "some status", "some remark"

Of course... that requires logic on the php end, of tying sick_day to max_sick_leaves, so it'd be better to have a employee_day_off_types table too..., but this can get you started, we really need more details.